# Site runs fine locally. After putting it under public_html folder my .glb model gets a "404 (Not Found)"

Tags: .htaccess, three.js, gltf

This is my first go at web programming and I'm really confused. I used GLTFLoader to load glb file into the scene which ran fine locally, but once transferring to public_html it now receives 404 not found.

linked here http://digitalmedia.rmit.edu.au/~s3646460/_Homage/

I have set all the directories and files permissions to 755 so understand it is possibly a .htaccess, mime-type, or XMLHttpRequest matter, but I really don't understand these things yet or how to go about altering them.

Any help or direction is appreciated as I don't know anything :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is looking for your file in the wrong place.
Open the browser dev tools and you can see the error.
The url it is looking to is: "http://digitalmedia.rmit.edu.au/3d/modelhomage1.glb"
But the file is at: "http://digitalmedia.rmit.edu.au/~s3646460/_Homage/3d/modelhomage1.glb"

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that you had to change directories when putting things on a different server but it makes sense. Also weird to me that the textures etc didn't require any path changes.
I don't have the 404 message anymore but the model still isn't loading 

Comment: update: thanks 2pha! It does actually work but loading times are huge. Which is an issue with my internet and probably unnecessary large file size for the model.

Comment: yeh, the file is a little large I think... 96MB